# AWS - How my single EC2 micro instance can cross 750 hour limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS, my site is up and running since three weeks. While my billing shows:

```
Service      Month-to-date   actual usage   Month-end    forecasted usage   Free Tier usage limit
EC2 -Linux   750.00 Hrs      100.00%        930.00 Hrs   124.00%            750 Hrs
```

Also Amazon site states that:

> > 750 hours of Amazon EC2 Linux t2.micro instance usage (1 GiB of memory and 32-bit and 64-bit platform support) – enough hours to run continuously each month*

While there can be maximum 31*24 = 744 hours in a month, so how can my single EC2 instance exceed the limit just in three weeks in terms of number of hours? Would appreciate any help to make me understand.

thank you.

Comment: Was there only 1 micro instance running at any given time for the entire month? Did you stop and restart your micro instance at all during the month, or was it running straight through with no stops?

Comment: I didn't restart, it was single and running all the time.

Comment: Also, check all regions to make sure that an instance wasn't started in another region and forgotten.

Comment: If there was only the one instance running for the entire time, then AWS support is the only people who can tell you why you're billed so much. Contact AWS support.

Comment: Yes I just checked all regions and saw that another instance was running in other region definitely my mistake. Appreciate your help to figure out this part because billing section doesn't describe well in detail (number of instances) being charged. thank a lot.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The [AWS Free Usage Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) provides particular services for free during the first 12 months of an AWS account.

Full details are available at: https://aws.amazon.com/free/

The free tier for Amazon EC2 provides 750 hours per month for a t2.micro Linux instance *and* 750 hours per month for a t2.micro Windows instance (but make sure you choose an AMI that is "free tier eligible").

These hours can be used by one instance running for the full month (31 days * 24 hours = 744 hours) or by multiple Amazon EC2 instances used during the month. Any hours in excess of the free tier will be charged at On-Demand prices (unless a Reserved Instance applies, or an instance is launched as a Spot instance).

If you have used more than 750 hours in a month, it would be because **more than one instance was running**. This includes instances running across *all* regions, so check whether instances have been run in other regions.

The AWS billing pages can provide details about which services have been used, and also provide a [breakdown of usage of the Free Usage Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-monitor-your-aws-free-tier-usage/).

Comment: So if this was accepted as the answer, I take it more than one instance was going on (despite him saying no in the comments)? Just got started with AWS and am trying to make sure I understand the rates properly.

Comment: Yes, more than one instance was in use. The OP states in a comment that there was another instance in a different region.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Running an EC2 instance using elastic beanstalk, seems to eat up my free hours very quickly.

Our product is not live - I just do `ebs deploy` a couple of times and poof. Wonder why that is...

Comment: @Qasim Please create a new Question rather than asking via a comment on an old question.

Comment: does it have anything to do with cpu utilization? some free credits per hour and we exceed tht then the hours will be utilized more?

Answer (score 1):

Agree that billing page doesn't help in getting complete clarity over the number of EC2 instances running and also which regions, unless we manually go our our regions dropdown and check one by one.

Wanted to add a screenshot from AWS Console, which says EC2 global view, shows two tabs, global view and regional view.

Hope this helps in getting better clarity on the EC2 instances running across all regions globally if it's more than 1 instance.
See the highlighted part.

[image: AWS EC2 Global view]